# Definition of inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In the definition, we defined linearity in the first argument, Hermitian symmetry. And these two imply anti-linearity in second argument. Is it equivalent, if I cancel the Hermitian symmetry and only define linearity and anti-linearity in first and second argument respectively? Namely,

$(x,ay+bz)=a^*(x,y)+b^*(x,z)\wedge(ax+by,z)=a(x,z)+b(y,z)$

$\Rightarrow (y,x)=(x,y)^*$

Comment: If in addition to the sesquilinearity you require positive (semi)definiteness, that implies the hermitian symmetry.

Comment: An inner product is by definition positive definite. So that has to appear somewhere in the list. What you need for the hermitian symmetry, given sesquilinearity, is that you have $(x,x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x$. That is of course implied by $(x,x) \geqslant 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Is semidefiniteness strong enough to imply hermitian symmetry? E.g. if the definition of scalar product can be given by a matrix M
: symmetry of sesquilinear (.,.) is equivalent to M is self-adjoit. So M is positive (semi)definite, converse doesnt hold for sure. However, here we're trying to prove from positive semideiniteness to hermitian..

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be a sesquilinear form (linear in the first argument, antilinear in the second). Then you have the polarisation identity $$4\sigma(x,y) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 i^k\cdot \sigma(x + i^k y, x+ i^k y).$$ Now $\sigma(i^a u, i^av) = \sigma(u,v)$ for all $u,v$ and $a$, so $$4\sigma(x,y) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 i^k \sigma(y + i^{-k} x, y + i^{-k} x) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 i^k\sigma(y + i^{4-k}x, y + i^{4-k}x) = \sum_{m = 0}^3 i^{4-m}\sigma(y + i^m x, y+ i^m x).$$ For $m \in \{0,2\}$ we have $i^{4-m} = i^m$ and for $m\in \{1,3\}$ we have $i^{4-m} = -i^m$. So if $\sigma(u,u) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $u$,

Comment: then it follows that $\sigma(x,y) = \overline{\sigma(y,x)}$ for all $x,y$. Conversely, if we have the hermitian symmetry, then of course $\sigma(u,u) \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $u$. Note that it is essential that we have a complex vector space, the argument doesn't work for bilinear forms on real vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.

For instance, on $\mathbb{C}^n$, take any matrix $M\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that is not hermitian, and put $(X,Y)\mapsto X^t M \overline{Y}$.

Comment: Yes you are Right! But Daniel (above) was saying that additional positive semidefiniteness can imply hermitian. But I disagree.